# How to switch desktop layout from tty before startx?

Tags: tty, xserver

I would like to login with the same user in another tty, but each tty should have different desktop environment like KDE and LXDE.

How can I use tty to start X server by providing the desktop type?

Comment: Seems duplicate of  https://askubuntu.com/questions/416825/how-to-quick-switch-between-desktop-environments-in-the-running-desktop-session